# Login page in python django

Tags: django, authentication

Hi i'm just trying to create my login page but i have an error. i want to import the Login View and use the username and password from the admin that i created.

i tried this code but i have an error.

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from gomo_websys.views import login_page, home_page
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

urlpatterns = [
    path('' , LoginView, {'template_name': 'login/Login.html'}),
    path('home/' , home_page, name='home_page'),
```

Login.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}
<title>Login</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<p>
  You can log in here!
</p>
<h2>Login</h2>
<form method="post">
  {% crsf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def login_page(request):
    return render(request, "login/Login.html")
```

i have an error result.

Comment: what is error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

In urls.py

```
   from django.urls import path, include
   from django.contrib.auth import views

   urlpatterns = [
       path('',include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
   ]
```

so now you can got to `example.com/login` to go to default login page by django
so now you can got to `example.com/logout` to logout

To use custom login page , make a folder called `registraions` in `templates` folder and your login html page with `login.html` name

you can control on which you land after login and logout from below code

```
LOGIN_URL = 'login' 
#'login' is the url where you go if you use @login_required decorator if you are not logged in

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'index' 
# 'index' is url where you go after logging in

LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'login'
# 'login' is url where you go after logged out
```